# How to map an axd which not physically exist in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am working on a blog site, upgrading it to MVC3.

I have this in web.config:

```
<add name="RssHandler" verb="*" path="rss.axd" type="Blog.Web.RSSHandler, Blog.Web"/>
```

So, if I access the rss.axd directly from the url, it works:

```
http://mydomain/rss.axd
```

Now I want to use `http://mydomain/RSS` to map the rss.axd, so in the global.asax, i tried

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("RSS-View", "RSS", "~/rss.axd", false);
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    ...
}
```

but i got a 404 error, because the rss.axd is not a physical file that exists in the website folder.

In the past, i use UrlRewrite to do this and it works, like this:

```
<LookFor>~/RSS<LookFor>
<SendTo>~/rss.axd</SendTo>
```

So, in MVC3 is there anyway to do this "ReWrite", not "Route"? I don't want to use redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in support available for routing to http handlers.

One possibility is to write a custom route handler ([`IRouteHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.iroutehandler.aspx)) that will return an instance of your `RSSHandler`:

```
public class RssRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        return new Blog.Web.RSSHandler();
    }
}
```

and finally you could register this route:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.Add("RSS-View", new Route("rss", new RssRouteHandler()));

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Now we are no longer going through the virtual `rss.axd` address. When a request is made to `/rss` we directly serve this request through our custom route handler, as if we had the following in web.config:

```
<add name="RssHandler" verb="*" path="rss" type="Blog.Web.RSSHandler, Blog.Web"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your great idea. But finally i found an eazy way (i don't know if this is good practice to use): I add these into web.config/system.web: `<urlMappings enabled="true"> <add url="~/RSS" mappedUrl="~/rss.axd"/> </urlMappings>`